# How to draw a vertical line between images but not at the edges

Tags: css

Say you have three images in a row and you want to display a vertical line among them. I would use a border, but I don't want to display it on the extreme edges (left on the first image, right on the third image). What's the best strategy to achieve this by using CSS only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `last-child` pseudo selector to make sure the last image in your collection doesn't have the border:

```
img{
    border-right:1px solid #000;
}

img:last-child
{
    border-right:none;
}
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WvVHW/)

Browser support for `last-child` may vary.

If you need to support browsers where last-child isn't available you could apply a class to the last image and hook into it that way.

Comment: Browser support: [`:first-child`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t17), [`:last-child`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t35)

Answer (score 1):

If you're not planning on breaking out of just three images per row you can introduce a "middle" class that handles the borders and spacing in between, like so:

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSZ3KCafAVUhanaeaAsG0Q8lzdKKMOo7TP3H1W4TcMEcpVqtKTPVA&t=1" /></li>
        <li class="middle"><img src="http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSZ3KCafAVUhanaeaAsG0Q8lzdKKMOo7TP3H1W4TcMEcpVqtKTPVA&t=1" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSZ3KCafAVUhanaeaAsG0Q8lzdKKMOo7TP3H1W4TcMEcpVqtKTPVA&t=1" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
    width:662px;
}

.box li {
    float:left;
}

.middle {
    border:solid #000;
    border-width:0 1px 0 1px;
    margin:0 14px;
    padding:0 10px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/xba3r/1/)

This method works across all browsers, but as some of the posters already suggested you can also use the `:last-child` selector to do it more cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

best is to set left border and for `:first-child` remove

Answer (score 0):

Emm border-left on the last two images or border-right on the first two?

Comment: Maybe I should have added that the number of images is dynamic.